# What type of hinges to use to pivot at the corner of an outdoor enclosure?

Tags: hinges, gates

I'm building a simple outdoor enclosure for a rain barrel and assorted irrigation equipment. It’s a wooden frame wrapped around with cedar plank. On its front, a gate that pivots right from the corner.

For esthetic reasons, I would like to have only cedar plank visible at the corner. My idea was to overlap cedar plank on the side to the width of a gate frame (3/4", ~19 mm), then overlap the plank on the front to flush the edges with side surface.

Then, there’s a question of the hinges. I was looking at some outdoor fence gate hardware, and saw that basic T-hinge style operates correctly for my purposes, but I have concerns whether my set-up would cause any interference when opening.

And, there’s an issue with the mounting holes. In the attached sketch, I’ve drawn a hinge on the outside of the corner, but that pushes the hinge out to almost 1" and ¼ (31 mm) before the holes hit the edge of a structural frame member. I could conceivably place them directly onto the gate frame, routing the latter to set the hinges flush, then cover up with cedar plank, but that equates more work, and less simple.

[image: Schematic sketch of the corner cross-section]

Comment: Sometimes it takes more work to get the results one desires.  The old saying " If it were easy, everyone would do it."  applies here.  Often details that make one go "WOW" are those that took a great amount of time over the old "quick and easy".

Comment: So you don't want the framing to show on the exterior , but it's OK for the hinges to show?

Comment: @Huesmann, yes, I don't mind hinges, it's a utilitarian enclosure, rustic, akin to a fence (I'm actually using cedar fence pickets ripped into planks for siding), so inexpensive black or galvanized outdoor-rated hardware is what I'm looking for. I just want to see what types of hinges are available (I don't know the terminology, and couldn't find an overview online), so I can look beyond scant options in big stores.

Comment: I think the sketch you show is fine, but I would think you'd want hinges with two (or more) screws in both legs.

Comment: @Huesmann, strap hinges look like they would work. Hopefully, the gate won't be too heavy, since strap hinges don't have the amount of screws on the post side, like T-hinges do.

Comment: Strap hinge = piano hinge?